# Is this a good method of ensuring $_REQUEST data is safe?

Tags: php, html, security, xss, sanitization

Basically, my idea is that if I convert a string whose contents I cannot predict into a hex string, then in the script that receives the data, convert it back to a readable string, it will prevent any potential XSS vulnerabilities, as well as ensure that any special characters such as spaces, ampersands, question marks, etc. don't mess up execution of Script2.php.  Is this correct, or is there more I need to do?

In Script1.php:

```
echo('<TD><A HREF="Script2.php?reason=' .  bin2hex($input['reason']) . '">Proceed</A></TD>');
```

In Script2.php:

```
echo('<input type="text" name="reason">' . strlen($_REQUEST['reason'])?pack('H*', $_REQUEST['reason']):'<I>No reason specified</I>' . '</input>');
```

Comment: That would make sense for transferring binary data. The ordinary `urlencode()` and `htmlspecialchars()` marshalling would make more sense. In particular since you output the text anyway in script2, you *do need* proper context escaping for html output.

Comment: This entirely misunderstands what injection vulnerabilities are. The hex-encoding provides no protection, you can go to `?reason=3c7363726970743e616c657274282758535327293c2f7363726970743e` and that injects `<script>alert('XSS')</script>` into the resulting page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, there is exactly one thing that you need to look out for: when you issue a command to an external system, you have to make sure that the command means exactly what you think it means.

If you are programming in PHP, you frequently deal with two external systems:

1. the web browser to wich you send your HTML,
2. the database where you store data.

For point 1, filter data that comes from the database through [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php). There are cases when you don't want to do this, but in those cases you have to know *exactly* why this does not compromise the security of your users.

For point 2, use prepared statements to insert and update database records. For new code, there are *no* exceptions, regardless of where the data is comming from. For old code, that uses interfaces that do not support prepared statements, use something like `mysql_real_escape_string()` to prepare values for inserting into or updating the database; again, regardless of where the data is comming from.

These two points are technical requirements (i.e. they are imposed by the technology that you are using). Additionally, there might be business requirements (like a credit card number being valid, a birthdate beeing before Aug 30th, 1995, a venue can only be booked for up to 7 days, whatever). Technical requirements and business requirements change at different rates, so you should handle them in different components. Don't mix preparing data to be technically fit for insertion into the database with validating whether the data meets your business needs.

Applying this to your special scenario, it seems that in Script1.php, you want to use some data in the query string of a URL in a HTML document. That's what [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) is for. In Script2.php, the browser has sent you data that you want to sent back to the browser. This is usually not critical for your or your users security. Still, the data must be passed through `htmlspecialchars`, because if the user sends `</input>` as `$_REQUEST['reason']` it will confuse the user. It is not clear, what you intend with `strlen` and `pack`; don't do that, it serves no purpose other than to confuse fellow developers (which is bad), users (which is also bad) and potential attackers (which they regard as a challange rather than a hindrance).

Answer (score 0):

OWASP has some very detailed information on how to best prevent XSS: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#A_Positive_XSS_Prevention_Model